# Why does my i class "icon-google-plus" doesn't appear?

Tags: html, css

```css
#footer  .social-links  .facebook a{text-align:center;float: left;width: 46px;height: 46px;border: 2px solid white;border-radius: 100%;margin-right: 25px; /*space between*/
    display: flex;align-items: flex-start;transition: all 0.4s;-webkit-transition: all 0.4s;background-color:#3D5A96;} 
#footer  .social-links  .facebook a i{font-size: 30px;align-self:center;color: white;transition: all 0.4s;-webkit-transition: all 0.4s;margin: 0 auto;}
#footer  .social-links .facebook a i::before{display:inline-block;text-decoration:none;}

#footer  .social-links  .twitter a{text-align:center;float: left;width: 46px;height: 46px;border: 2px solid white;border-radius: 100%;margin-right: 25px; /*space between*/
    display: flex;align-items: flex-start;transition: all 0.4s;-webkit-transition: all 0.4s;background-color:#00B4D6;} 
#footer  .social-links  .twitter a i{font-size: 30px;align-self:center;color: white;transition: all 0.4s;-webkit-transition: all 0.4s;margin: 0 auto;}
#footer  .social-links .twitter a i::before{display:inline-block;text-decoration:none;}

#footer  .social-links  .google a{text-align:center;float: left;width: 46px;height: 46px;border: 2px solid white;border-radius: 100%;margin-right: 25px; /*space between*/
    display: flex;align-items: flex-start;transition: all 0.4s;-webkit-transition: all 0.4s;background-color:#DC4637;} 
#footer  .social-links  .google a i{font-size: 30px;align-self:center;color: white;transition: all 0.4s;-webkit-transition: all 0.4s;margin: 0 auto;}
#footer  .social-links .google a i::before{display:inline-block;text-decoration:none;}

#footer  .social-links  .youtube a{text-align:center;float: left;width: 46px;height: 46px;border: 2px solid white;border-radius: 100%;margin-right: 25px; /*space between*/
    display: flex;align-items: flex-start;transition: all 0.4s;-webkit-transition: all 0.4s;background-color:#C00000;} 
#footer  .social-links  .youtube a i{font-size: 30px;align-self:center;color: white;transition: all 0.4s;-webkit-transition: all 0.4s;margin: 0 auto;}
#footer  .social-links .youtube a i::before{display:inline-block;text-decoration:none;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div id="footer">
<div class="social-links">
          <div class="facebook"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" ><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
       <div class="twitter"><a href="https://www.twitter.com" ><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
       <div class="google"><a href="https://www.google.com" ><i class="icon-google-plus icon-1" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
       <div class="youtube"><a href="https://www.youtube.com" ><i class="fa fa-youtube fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
      </div>
            </div>
```

My facebook, twitter, and youtube icons appear but not the google plus icon. Why is it like that?! Can you please help me fix my code, i already have a running snippet of it, thank you for your kindness :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd assume you haven't included whatever icon font the `"icon-google-plus icon-1"` refers to.  But since font-awesome includes a google plus icon, you could just swap it for `fa fa-google-plus`:

```css
#footer  .social-links  .facebook a{text-align:center;float: left;width: 46px;height: 46px;border: 2px solid white;border-radius: 100%;margin-right: 25px; /*space between*/
    display: flex;align-items: flex-start;transition: all 0.4s;-webkit-transition: all 0.4s;background-color:#3D5A96;} 
#footer  .social-links  .facebook a i{font-size: 30px;align-self:center;color: white;transition: all 0.4s;-webkit-transition: all 0.4s;margin: 0 auto;}
#footer  .social-links .facebook a i::before{display:inline-block;text-decoration:none;}

#footer  .social-links  .twitter a{text-align:center;float: left;width: 46px;height: 46px;border: 2px solid white;border-radius: 100%;margin-right: 25px; /*space between*/
    display: flex;align-items: flex-start;transition: all 0.4s;-webkit-transition: all 0.4s;background-color:#00B4D6;} 
#footer  .social-links  .twitter a i{font-size: 30px;align-self:center;color: white;transition: all 0.4s;-webkit-transition: all 0.4s;margin: 0 auto;}
#footer  .social-links .twitter a i::before{display:inline-block;text-decoration:none;}

#footer  .social-links  .google a{text-align:center;float: left;width: 46px;height: 46px;border: 2px solid white;border-radius: 100%;margin-right: 25px; /*space between*/
    display: flex;align-items: flex-start;transition: all 0.4s;-webkit-transition: all 0.4s;background-color:#DC4637;} 
#footer  .social-links  .google a i{font-size: 30px;align-self:center;color: white;transition: all 0.4s;-webkit-transition: all 0.4s;margin: 0 auto;}
#footer  .social-links .google a i::before{display:inline-block;text-decoration:none;}

#footer  .social-links  .youtube a{text-align:center;float: left;width: 46px;height: 46px;border: 2px solid white;border-radius: 100%;margin-right: 25px; /*space between*/
    display: flex;align-items: flex-start;transition: all 0.4s;-webkit-transition: all 0.4s;background-color:#C00000;} 
#footer  .social-links  .youtube a i{font-size: 30px;align-self:center;color: white;transition: all 0.4s;-webkit-transition: all 0.4s;margin: 0 auto;}
#footer  .social-links .youtube a i::before{display:inline-block;text-decoration:none;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div id="footer">
<div class="social-links">
          <div class="facebook"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" ><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
       <div class="twitter"><a href="https://www.twitter.com" ><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
       <div class="google"><a href="https://www.google.com" ><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
       <div class="youtube"><a href="https://www.youtube.com" ><i class="fa fa-youtube fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
      </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: hmm the "fa-google-plus" has Capital G. But i need the small one that's why i used icon-google-plus :(

Answer (score 0):

Your facebook, twitter and youtube icons are loaded from font-awesome package. Google+ icon, however, is defined completely different.

Maybe you should specify it as "fa fa-google-plus", as described [here](http://fontawesome.io/icon/google-plus/)?

Comment: hmm the "fa-google-plus" has Capital G. But i need the small one that's why i used icon-google-plus :(

Comment: But how is this CSS class defined and where? Is it your own CSS class? If so, please include it into the question.